# is there any way to print a value of the object?

Tags: spring-boot, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I am using java spring boot and I got an errorrelated to the `Aggregation.group` I want to print the contents of the object, but instead I get the result which looks like object itself

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation@5ef26c0d
```

What I want to get the value of the object. Is there any way to print it out?
I have tried these commands so far:

```
System.out.println(Aggregation.group());
System.out.println(Aggregation.group("a").addToSet("b").as("references"));
```

Please help me how to print the values.

Comment: Your Object GroupOperation is probably not overriding toString()

Answer (score 0):

In general, printing an object results in calling its `toString()` method. To modify how the print of an object looks like, just override the `toString()` method in the relevant class.

In your case, it is a foreign class of another library you use. The easier way how to find the issue is to use the debugger of your IDE. Set some breakpoints where the debugger should stop the programme to investigate variables values at this point in time. It is often quite cumbersome to print variable values at the console.

Depending on the IDE you use: the usage of the debugging function [in Eclipse](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html), [in JetBrains' IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html) and [in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging).

Comment: I already usiing .toString() and debugging but.. i couldn't find it.. so i asked here..

Comment: Then, you should give some more insights in what you are doing.